# Jquery zoom, zooms only one image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to make a product page with gallery (clickable small thumbnails on the side) which opens a large image on the right side. 
Jquery zoom only displays the zoom on the first image, when the other images are displayed the zoom is still on the first image.

[image: View of the page]

Here is my code:
HTML

```
<section class="product-page">
        <div class="thumbnails">
            <div class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/Thumbnails/thumb-air-force-right-side.png" alt="thumb-air-force-right-side" onclick="right()"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/Thumbnails/thumb-air-force-left-side.png" alt="thumb-air-force-left-side" onclick="left()"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/Thumbnails/thumb-air-force-bottom-side.png" alt="thumb-air-force-bottom-side" onclick="bottom()"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/Thumbnails/thumb-air-force-pair-side.png" alt="thumb-air-force-pair-side" onclick="pairSide()"></a></div>
            <div class="thumb"><a href="#"><img src="img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/Thumbnails/thumb-air-force-pair-top.png" alt="thumb-air-force-pair-top" onclick="pairTop()"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="img-display">
            <span class='zoom' id='shoe1'>
                <img id="img-area" src="img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/air-force-right-side.png" alt="air-force-right-side" width="320" height="320">
            </span>
            <span class='zoom1' id='shoe1'>
                <img class="hidden" id="img-area" src="img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/air-force-left-side.png" alt="air-force-left-side" width="320" height="320">
            </span>
            <span class='zoom' id='shoe3'>
                <img class="hidden" id="img-area" src="img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/air-force-bottom-side.png" alt="air-force-bottom-side">
            </span>
            <span class='zoom' id='shoe4'>
                <img class="hidden" id="img-area" src="img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/air-force-pair-side.png" alt="air-force-pair-side">
            </span>
            <span class='zoom' id='shoe5'>
                <img class="hidden" id="img-area" src="img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/air-force-pair-top.png" alt="air-force-pair-top">
            </span>
        </div>
    </section>
```

JS for image changing while clicking on the thumbnail images

```
    var img = document.getElementById("img-area");
        function right(){
            img.src='img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/air-force-right-side.png';
        }
        function left(){
            img.src='img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/air-force-left-side.png';
        }
        function bottom(){
            img.src='img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/air-force-bottom-side.png';
        }
        function pairSide(){
            img.src='img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/air-force-pair-side.png';
        }
        function pairTop(){
            img.src='img/nike/shoes/Air-force1/air-force-pair-top.png';
        }
```

And the Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shoe1').zoom();
    $('#shoe2').zoom();
    $('#shoe3').zoom();
    $('#shoe4').zoom();
    $('#shoe5').zoom();
});
```

How to make the changed image zoom in on hover?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have multiple `id="img-area"`'s

Comment: at a glance it looks like you're making this way harder than it needs to be. If you have jquery available, why are you using vanilla JS? Just to learn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something as simple as this could be achievable without causing repetitive strain injury.

For obvious reasons I haven't considered image preloading, etc, but this is something I hope you can take inspiration from.

Your `img-display` should be treated as a canvas. Bind a single event handler to links wrapped around thumbs who's `href` attribute contains the larger image you want to load in the canvas area. This event handler simply rotates your thumbnails, but uses the larger image and passes that to both the canvas image and the jQuery zoom plugin API whilst toggling active states of thumbs (as an aesthetic suggestion).

Why `href`? As an example, screen readers still need to be able to follow these links. I'm thinking accessibility ftw.

Images courtesy of [JD Sports](https://www.jdsports.co.uk/product/grey-nike-air-force-1-essential-jewel/15958937/).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.zoom').zoom();
  $('.thumb').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thumb = $(e.delegateTarget);
    if (!thumb.hasClass('active')) {
      thumb.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      $('.zoom')
        .zoom({
          url: this.href
        })
        .find('img').attr('src', this.href);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.product-page {
  display: flex;
}

.img-display {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 372px;
}

.thumb {
  opacity: .7;
  margin: 0 .25rem .25rem 0;
  width: 120px;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
}

.thumb:hover,
.thumb.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.zoom {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-zoom/1.7.21/jquery.zoom.min.js"></script>

<section class="product-page">
  <div class="thumbnails">
    <div class="thumb active">
      <a href="https://i8.amplience.net/i/jpl/jd_334285_a?qlt=92&w=750&h=531&v=1">
        <img src="https://i8.amplience.net/i/jpl/jd_334285_a?qlt=92&w=750&h=531&v=1" alt="thumb-air-force-right-side">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
      <a href="https://i8.amplience.net/i/jpl/jd_334285_b?qlt=92&w=950&h=673&v=1">
        <img src="https://i8.amplience.net/i/jpl/jd_334285_b?qlt=92&w=950&h=673&v=1" alt="thumb-air-force-left-side">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
      <a href="https://i8.amplience.net/i/jpl/jd_334285_e?qlt=92&w=950&h=673&v=1">
        <img src="https://i8.amplience.net/i/jpl/jd_334285_e?qlt=92&w=950&h=673&v=1" alt="thumb-air-force-bottom-side">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="img-display">
    <span class="zoom">
      <img src="https://i8.amplience.net/i/jpl/jd_334285_a?qlt=92&w=750&h=531&v=1" alt="">
    </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

@perocvrc

Please try below code it works perfectly as per your requirement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.main-view-page {
  display: flex;
}

.full-screen-img {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.sideimg {
  opacity: .7;
  margin: 0 .1rem .1rem 0;
  width: 120px;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-out;
}

.sideimg:hover,
.sideimg.active {
  opacity: 1;
  width:135px;
}

.zoom-in {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-zoom/1.7.21/jquery.zoom.min.js"></script>

<script> 
$(function() {
  $('.zoom-in').zoom();
  $('.sideimg').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thumb = $(e.delegateTarget);
    if (!thumb.hasClass('active')) {
      thumb.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      $('.zoom-in')
        .zoom({
          url: this.href
        })
        .find('img').attr('src', this.href);
    }
  });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<section class="main-view-page">
  <div class="thumbnails">
    <div class="sideimg">
      <a href="https://st2.depositphotos.com/2038977/8502/i/950/depositphotos_85027142-stock-photo-goats-grazing-on-the-alpine.jpg">
        <img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/2038977/8502/i/950/depositphotos_85027142-stock-photo-goats-grazing-on-the-alpine.jpg" alt="thumb-air-force-right-side">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sideimg active">
      <a href="https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/b/1/c/162815.jpg">
        <img src="https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/b/1/c/162815.jpg" alt="thumb-air-force-left-side">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sideimg">
      <a href="https://jooinn.com/images/cabin-with-beautiful-view.jpg">
        <img src="https://jooinn.com/images/cabin-with-beautiful-view.jpg" alt="thumb-air-force-bottom-side">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sideimg">
      <a href="https://www.principlesinsight.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/clouds-conifer-daylight-371589.jpg">
        <img src="https://www.principlesinsight.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/clouds-conifer-daylight-371589.jpg" alt="thumb-air-force-bottom-side">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-screen-img">
    <span class="zoom-in">
      <img src="https://wallpaperplay.com/walls/full/b/1/c/162815.jpg" alt="main-view-images">
    </span>
  </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.
Thank you.

Comment: This is just a direct copy of my solution with renamed classes. Do you always take credit for other people solutions??